# Reload table data after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using this ajax call to do some changes in database. I need to refresh the table data when we click ok, without reloading the page. If i refresh the page table will be removed.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET", 
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "processOrgDisburse.php",           
    success: function(response) {  
      if(response[0]=='OK'){
          $('.camt').html(response[1]);/*added by das comment*/
       document.getElementById(orgBal).innerHTML=response[2];          
       document.getElementById('amtSpan').innerHTML=response[1];       
       document.getElementById(id).value="";
       //tired this $("#testTab").load(); but not working
       // testTab is an table id
       }  
      else{
          alert("The cause balance is lower than the amount disbursed. Please have additional funds added to the cause balance");
          document.getElementById(id).value="";


       }
     }
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: what is source of data to refresh table?

Comment: if you make a request to server that requires table refresh, why aren't you sending back table html or json data to parse to html to repopulate table? That's what normal work flow would be

Comment: @charlietfl i think that will increase server load..if table refresh is not possible then i will do that.

Comment: then explain what you were expecting? How big is table?

Comment: @charlietfl tables are not too big, they have 2 fields max.At client side I am displaying 2 fields and one textbox in table. when i enter value in textbox, value get subtracted from one table and add into another table. This is done through mysql query. When query is executed successfully. Alert is displayed. Now i want to display the updated valued in table without refreshing the page

Comment: that can be done with simple jquery, update field or text...is different concept than reload table